Boost.Voronoi generates incorrect Voronoi cells with floating-point input in C++
I'm working with experimental data representing head positions of pedestrians in meters within a room. My goal is to generate Voronoi cells in C++ that surround each pedestrian, allowing me to calculate the areas of these cells. However, after generating the Voronoi cells using Boost.Voronoi and plotting them, I found that the cells are incorrectly drawn – the points are not properly separated into individual cells as expected.
I came across a note in the Boost.Voronoi documentation that the input coordinates are, by default, expected to be integers. To work with real-world coordinates, I defined my custom point type that allows the use of floating-point values.
Below is the code I used to generate the Voronoi diagram and output the data in textual form. This code compiles with g++-13, but clang-tidy raises an error during the construction of segments:
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <format>

#include <boost/polygon/polygon.hpp>
#include <boost/polygon/voronoi.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/box.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/point.hpp>
#include <boost/polygon/point_data.hpp>
#include <boost/polygon/polygon.hpp>
#include <boost/polygon/voronoi.hpp>
#include <boost/polygon/voronoi_diagram.hpp>

using namespace std;


struct Position
{
    using coordinate_type = double;

    coordinate_type x, y;
};

using coordinate_type = Position::coordinate_type;
using segment_type = boost::polygon::segment_data<coordinate_type>;
using VoronoiDiagram = boost::polygon::voronoi_diagram<coordinate_type>;

/// settings necessarily for boost to be able to use Position as points:
template <>
struct boost::polygon::geometry_concept<Position> { typedef point_concept type; };

template <>
struct boost::polygon::point_traits<Position>
{
    using coordinate_type = ::coordinate_type;

    static inline coordinate_type get(const Position& point, boost::polygon::orientation_2d orient)
    {
        return (orient == boost::polygon::HORIZONTAL) ? point.x : point.y;
    }
};
using polygonF = boost::geometry::model::polygon<Position, /*ClockWise=*/false, /*Closed=*/false>;

/// settings required to use boost::geometry::area(polygonF):
namespace boost { namespace geometry { namespace traits {

template <>
struct tag<Position> {
    using type = point_tag;
};

template <>
struct coordinate_type<Position> {
    using type = Position::coordinate_type;
};

template <>
struct coordinate_system<Position> {
    using type = cs::cartesian;
};

template <>
struct dimension<Position> : boost::mpl::int_<2> {};

template <>
struct access<Position, 0> {
    static double get(const Position& p) { return p.x; }
    static void set(Position& p, const double& value) { p.x = value; }
};

template <>
struct access<Position, 1> {
    static double get(const Position& p) { return p.y; }
    static void set(Position& p, const double& value) { p.y = value; }
};
}}} // namespace boost::geometry::traits


polygonF verticesOfCell(const VoronoiDiagram::cell_type& voronoiCell)
{
    polygonF polygon;

    const auto* edge = voronoiCell.incident_edge();
    do {
        if (!edge)
        {
            break;
        }

        if (edge->is_primary())
        {
            if (edge->is_finite())
            {
                auto v0 = edge->vertex0();
                auto v1 = edge->vertex1();
                polygon.outer().emplace_back(v0->x(), v0->y());
                polygon.outer().emplace_back(v1->x(), v1->y());
            }
        }
        edge = edge->next();
    } while (edge != voronoiCell.incident_edge());

    return polygon;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    //////////////// configuration points and segments:
    std::vector<Position> positions
        = {Position{0.476191, -0.952381},  Position{-0, -0.952381},
           Position{-0.476191, -0.952381}, Position{-0.476191, -1.42857},
           Position{-0.952381, -1.42857},  Position{-1.90476, -0.952381},
           Position{-1.42857, -1.42857},   Position{-1.90476, -1.42857},
           Position{-2.38095, -1.90476},   Position{-1.42857, -2.38095},
           Position{-1.42857, -1.90476},   Position{-0.952381, -2.85714},
           Position{-0.952381, -3.33333},  Position{-0, -3.80952},
           Position{0.952381, -4.28571},   Position{0.476191, -4.28571},
           Position{0.476191, -3.80952},   Position{0.952381, -3.33333},
           Position{0.476191, -3.33333},   Position{-0, -2.38095},
           Position{0.476191, -2.38095},   Position{0.952381, -1.90476},
           Position{0.476191, -1.90476},   Position{-0, -1.90476},
           Position{0.476191, -0.476191},  Position{-0.952381, -0.952381},
           Position{0.476191, -1.42857},   Position{-0.476191, -2.38095},
           Position{-0.952381, -2.38095},  Position{-2.38095, -2.85714},
           Position{-1.90476, -3.33333},   Position{-1.42857, -3.33333},
           Position{-0, -2.85714},         Position{-0.476191, -2.85714},
           Position{-0, -3.33333},         Position{-0, -4.76191},
           Position{0.952381, -2.38095},   Position{0.952381, -2.85714},
           Position{0.476191, -2.85714},   Position{-0.476191, -1.90476},
           Position{0.952381, -3.80952},   Position{1.42857, -2.85714},
           Position{1.90476, -2.38095},    Position{0.952381, -4.76191},
           Position{-0.476191, -5.2381},   Position{0.476191, -5.2381},
           Position{1.90476, -3.33333},    Position{-2.85714, -2.38095},
           Position{-2.38095, -1.42857},   Position{-2.38095, -0.952381},
           Position{-1.42857, -2.85714},   Position{-1.90476, -1.90476},
           Position{1.42857, -1.90476},    Position{2.38095, -2.85714},
           Position{2.38095, -1.42857},    Position{2.38095, -0.952381},
           Position{1.90476, -1.42857},    Position{2.38095, -1.90476},
           Position{-1.90476, -2.38095},   Position{0.952381, -0.952381},
           Position{-3.33333, -3.33333},   Position{-3.80952, -2.38095},
           Position{-3.80952, -1.42857},   Position{-3.33333, -1.90476},
           Position{-3.33333, -0.952381},  Position{-0.476191, -4.28571},
           Position{-0, -1.42857},         Position{-0.952381, -1.90476}};

    std::vector<segment_type> segments;
    segments.emplace_back(Position(-6.5, -5.5), Position(3.5, -5.5)); // for clang can be compile error, for g++ compiles
    segments.emplace_back(Position(3.5, -5.5), Position(3.5, 3));
    segments.emplace_back(Position(3.5, 3), Position(-6.5, 3));
    segments.emplace_back(Position(-6.5, 3), Position(-6.5, -5.5));

    //////////////// construction of Voronoi diagram + printing cells
    VoronoiDiagram vd;
    boost::polygon::construct_voronoi(begin(positions), end(positions), begin(segments), end(segments), &vd);

    unsigned int cell_index = 0;
    for (auto it = vd.cells().begin(); it != vd.cells().end(); ++it) {
        if (it->contains_point()) {
            switch (it->source_category())
            {
                case boost::polygon::SOURCE_CATEGORY_SINGLE_POINT:
                {
                    std::size_t index = it->source_index();
                    auto p = positions[index];
                    cout << format("Cell #{} contains a point: ({:.2f}, {:.2f})", cell_index, p.x, p.y) << endl;
                    break;
                }
                case boost::polygon::SOURCE_CATEGORY_SEGMENT_START_POINT:
                {
                    std::size_t index = it->source_index() - positions.size();
                    auto p0 = low(segments[index]);
                    cout << format("Cell #{} contains segment start point: ({:.2f}, {:.2f})", cell_index, p0.x(), p0.y()) << endl;
                    break;
                }
                case boost::polygon::SOURCE_CATEGORY_SEGMENT_END_POINT:
                {
                    std::size_t index = it->source_index() - positions.size();
                    auto p1 = high(segments[index]);
                    cout << format("Cell #{} contains segment end point: ({:.2f}, {:.2f})", cell_index, p1.x(), p1.y()) << endl;
                    break;
                }
            }

            auto cellPolygon = verticesOfCell(*it);
            if (!cellPolygon.outer().empty()) {
                cout << "\t[vertices:" << cellPolygon.outer().size() << "]";
                if (boost::geometry::is_valid(cellPolygon))
                {
                    cout << "{area:" << boost::geometry::area(cellPolygon) << "}";
                }
                for (int i = 0; i < cellPolygon.outer().size(); ++i) {
                    const auto &p = cellPolygon.outer()[i];
                    cout << "\t(" << p.x << ", " << p.y << "),";
                }
                cout << endl;
            }
        } else {
            std::size_t index = it->source_index() - positions.size();
            auto p0 = low(segments[index]);
            auto p1 = high(segments[index]);
            cout << format("Cell #{} contains a segment: ({:.2f}, {:.2f}) -> ({:.2f}, {:.2f})", cell_index, p0.x(), p0.y(), p1.x(), p1.y()) << endl;
        }
        ++cell_index;
    }
}

Here is an example of how the Voronoi cells are drawn (as you can see, the edges don't seem to be correctly drawn):

Additionally, for comparison, here's how the same data is visualized using scipy.Voronoi in Python (as I understand VOronoi diagrams this is correct code):

Question: How can I correctly generate and visualize Voronoi cells in Boost.Voronoi for floating-point input?
I should also note that Boost provides an example using OpenGL to visualize Voronoi cells, but this example is no longer compatible with Qt6. My intention is to find a proper solution that could also potentially serve as an updated example for the Boost library, replacing the outdated OpenGL approach.

Appendix:
Full C++ code which generates Voronoi diagrams and draws with QT:
Full code which generates Voronoi diagram and draws:
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <format>

#include <QtWidgets/QApplication>
#include <QtWidgets/QMainWindow>
#include <QtCharts/QChartView>
#include <QtCharts/QScatterSeries>
#include <QtCharts/QLineSeries>

#include <boost/polygon/polygon.hpp>
#include <boost/polygon/voronoi.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/box.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/point.hpp>
#include <boost/polygon/point_data.hpp>
#include <boost/polygon/polygon.hpp>
#include <boost/polygon/voronoi.hpp>
#include <boost/polygon/voronoi_diagram.hpp>

using namespace std;


struct Position
{
    using coordinate_type = double;

    coordinate_type x, y;

    bool operator<(Position rhs) const;
    bool operator==(Position rhs) const;
};

using coordinate_type = Position::coordinate_type;
using segment_type = boost::polygon::segment_data<coordinate_type>;
using VoronoiDiagram = boost::polygon::voronoi_diagram<coordinate_type>;

/// settings necessarily for boost to be able to use Position as points:
template <>
struct boost::polygon::geometry_concept<Position> { typedef point_concept type; };

template <>
struct boost::polygon::point_traits<Position>
{
    using coordinate_type = ::coordinate_type;

    static inline coordinate_type get(const Position& point, boost::polygon::orientation_2d orient)
    {
        return (orient == boost::polygon::HORIZONTAL) ? point.x : point.y;
    }
};
using polygonF = boost::geometry::model::polygon<Position, /*ClockWise=*/false, /*Closed=*/false>;

/// settings required to use boost::geometry::area(polygonF):
namespace boost { namespace geometry { namespace traits {

template <>
struct tag<Position> {
    using type = point_tag;
};

template <>
struct coordinate_type<Position> {
    using type = Position::coordinate_type;
};

template <>
struct coordinate_system<Position> {
    using type = cs::cartesian;
};

template <>
struct dimension<Position> : boost::mpl::int_<2> {};

template <>
struct access<Position, 0> {
    static double get(const Position& p) { return p.x; }
    static void set(Position& p, const double& value) { p.x = value; }
};

template <>
struct access<Position, 1> {
    static double get(const Position& p) { return p.y; }
    static void set(Position& p, const double& value) { p.y = value; }
};
}}} // namespace boost::geometry::traits


QPolygonF verticesOfCell(const VoronoiDiagram::cell_type& voronoiCell)
{
    QPolygonF polygon;

    const auto* edge = voronoiCell.incident_edge();
    do {
        if (!edge)
        {
            break;
        }

        if (edge->is_primary())
        {
            if (edge->is_finite())
            {
                auto v0 = edge->vertex0();
                auto v1 = edge->vertex1();
                polygon << QPointF{v0->x(), v0->y()};
                polygon << QPointF{v1->x(), v1->y()};
            }
        }
        edge = edge->next();
    } while (edge != voronoiCell.incident_edge());

    return polygon;
}
polygonF toBoostPolygon(const QPolygonF& polygonQt)
{
    polygonF polygon;
    for (const auto p : polygonQt)
        polygon.outer().emplace_back(p.x(), p.y());
    return polygon;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    //////////////// configuration points and segments:
    std::vector<Position> positions
        = {Position{0.476191, -0.952381},  Position{-0, -0.952381},
           Position{-0.476191, -0.952381}, Position{-0.476191, -1.42857},
           Position{-0.952381, -1.42857},  Position{-1.90476, -0.952381},
           Position{-1.42857, -1.42857},   Position{-1.90476, -1.42857},
           Position{-2.38095, -1.90476},   Position{-1.42857, -2.38095},
           Position{-1.42857, -1.90476},   Position{-0.952381, -2.85714},
           Position{-0.952381, -3.33333},  Position{-0, -3.80952},
           Position{0.952381, -4.28571},   Position{0.476191, -4.28571},
           Position{0.476191, -3.80952},   Position{0.952381, -3.33333},
           Position{0.476191, -3.33333},   Position{-0, -2.38095},
           Position{0.476191, -2.38095},   Position{0.952381, -1.90476},
           Position{0.476191, -1.90476},   Position{-0, -1.90476},
           Position{0.476191, -0.476191},  Position{-0.952381, -0.952381},
           Position{0.476191, -1.42857},   Position{-0.476191, -2.38095},
           Position{-0.952381, -2.38095},  Position{-2.38095, -2.85714},
           Position{-1.90476, -3.33333},   Position{-1.42857, -3.33333},
           Position{-0, -2.85714},         Position{-0.476191, -2.85714},
           Position{-0, -3.33333},         Position{-0, -4.76191},
           Position{0.952381, -2.38095},   Position{0.952381, -2.85714},
           Position{0.476191, -2.85714},   Position{-0.476191, -1.90476},
           Position{0.952381, -3.80952},   Position{1.42857, -2.85714},
           Position{1.90476, -2.38095},    Position{0.952381, -4.76191},
           Position{-0.476191, -5.2381},   Position{0.476191, -5.2381},
           Position{1.90476, -3.33333},    Position{-2.85714, -2.38095},
           Position{-2.38095, -1.42857},   Position{-2.38095, -0.952381},
           Position{-1.42857, -2.85714},   Position{-1.90476, -1.90476},
           Position{1.42857, -1.90476},    Position{2.38095, -2.85714},
           Position{2.38095, -1.42857},    Position{2.38095, -0.952381},
           Position{1.90476, -1.42857},    Position{2.38095, -1.90476},
           Position{-1.90476, -2.38095},   Position{0.952381, -0.952381},
           Position{-3.33333, -3.33333},   Position{-3.80952, -2.38095},
           Position{-3.80952, -1.42857},   Position{-3.33333, -1.90476},
           Position{-3.33333, -0.952381},  Position{-0.476191, -4.28571},
           Position{-0, -1.42857},         Position{-0.952381, -1.90476}};

    std::vector<segment_type> segments;
    segments.emplace_back(Position(-6.5, -5.5), Position(3.5, -5.5)); // for clang can be compile error, for g++ compiles
    segments.emplace_back(Position(3.5, -5.5), Position(3.5, 3));
    segments.emplace_back(Position(3.5, 3), Position(-6.5, 3));
    segments.emplace_back(Position(-6.5, 3), Position(-6.5, -5.5));

    //////////////// Qt's part - set up Widgets
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QMainWindow window;
    QChart *chart = new QChart();
    chart->setTitle("Voronoi Diagram Example");
    chart->setAnimationOptions(QChart::AllAnimations);

    QScatterSeries *pointsSeries = new QScatterSeries();
    pointsSeries->setName("Source Points (head positions)");
    pointsSeries->setMarkerSize(10.0);

    for (const auto &pos : positions) {
        pointsSeries->append(pos.x, pos.y);
    }

    QLineSeries *voronoiEdgesSeries = new QLineSeries();
    voronoiEdgesSeries->setName("Voronoi Edges");
    chart->addSeries(pointsSeries);

    QLineSeries *segmentsSeries = new QLineSeries();
    segmentsSeries->setName("Segments (room end)");

    //////////////// construction of Voronoi diagram + printing cells
    VoronoiDiagram vd;
    boost::polygon::construct_voronoi(begin(positions), end(positions), begin(segments), end(segments), &vd);

    unsigned int cell_index = 0;
    for (auto it = vd.cells().begin(); it != vd.cells().end(); ++it) {
        if (it->contains_point()) {
            switch (it->source_category())
            {
                case boost::polygon::SOURCE_CATEGORY_SINGLE_POINT:
                {
                    std::size_t index = it->source_index();
                    auto p = positions[index];
                    cout << format("Cell #{} contains a point: ({:.2f}, {:.2f})", cell_index, p.x, p.y) << endl;
                    break;
                }
                case boost::polygon::SOURCE_CATEGORY_SEGMENT_START_POINT:
                {
                    std::size_t index = it->source_index() - positions.size();
                    auto p0 = low(segments[index]);
                    cout << format("Cell #{} contains segment start point: ({:.2f}, {:.2f})", cell_index, p0.x(), p0.y()) << endl;
                    break;
                }
                case boost::polygon::SOURCE_CATEGORY_SEGMENT_END_POINT:
                {
                    std::size_t index = it->source_index() - positions.size();
                    auto p1 = high(segments[index]);
                    cout << format("Cell #{} contains segment end point: ({:.2f}, {:.2f})", cell_index, p1.x(), p1.y()) << endl;
                    break;
                }
            }

            auto cellPolygon = verticesOfCell(*it);
            if (!cellPolygon.empty()) {
                cout << "\t[vertices:" << cellPolygon.size() << "]";
                if (auto boostPolygon = toBoostPolygon(cellPolygon);
                    boost::geometry::is_valid(boostPolygon))
                {
                    cout << "{area:" << boost::geometry::area(boostPolygon) << "}";
                }
                for (int i = 0; i < cellPolygon.size(); ++i) {
                    const QPointF &p = cellPolygon[i];
                    const QPointF &p2 = cellPolygon[(i + 1) % cellPolygon.size()];
                    voronoiEdgesSeries->append(p.x(), p.y());
                    voronoiEdgesSeries->append(p2.x(), p2.y());
                    cout << "\t(" << p.x() << ", " << p.y() << "),";
                }
                cout << endl;
            }
        } else {
            std::size_t index = it->source_index() - positions.size();
            auto p0 = low(segments[index]);
            auto p1 = high(segments[index]);
            cout << format("Cell #{} contains a segment: ({:.2f}, {:.2f}) -> ({:.2f}, {:.2f})", cell_index, p0.x(), p0.y(), p1.x(), p1.y()) << endl;
        }
        ++cell_index;
    }

    //////////////// Qt: setting up charts && drawing && showing:
    for (const auto& segment : segments)
    {
        auto p0 = segment.low();
        auto p1 = segment.high();
        segmentsSeries->append(p0.x(), p0.y());
        segmentsSeries->append(p1.x(), p1.y());
    }

    chart->addSeries(voronoiEdgesSeries);
    chart->addSeries(segmentsSeries);

    chart->createDefaultAxes();
    chart->setDropShadowEnabled(false);

    QChartView *chartView = new QChartView(chart);
    chartView->setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);

    window.setCentralWidget(chartView);
    window.resize(800, 600);
    window.show();

    return app.exec();
}

Output of first code:
Cell #0 contains segment end point: (-6.50, -5.50)
Cell #1 contains a segment: (-6.50, 3.00) -> (-6.50, -5.50)
Cell #2 contains segment start point: (-6.50, 3.00)
Cell #3 contains a segment: (-6.50, -5.50) -> (3.50, -5.50)
Cell #4 contains a segment: (3.50, 3.00) -> (-6.50, 3.00)
Cell #5 contains a point: (-3.33, -3.33)
    [vertices:10]{area:2.60011} (-2, -3.75),    (-2, -3),   (-2, -3),   (-2.5, -2.5),   (-2.5, -2.5),   (-4.45833, -2.5),   (-4.45833, -2.5),   (-4.4641, -3.4641), (-4.4641, -3.4641), (-2, -3.75),
Cell #6 contains a point: (-3.81, -2.38)
    [vertices:8]{area:1.95833}  (-2.5, -2.5),   (-2.5, -1.5),   (-2.5, -1.5),   (-4.45833, -1.5),   (-4.45833, -1.5),   (-4.45833, -2.5),   (-4.45833, -2.5),   (-2.5, -2.5),
Cell #7 contains a point: (-3.81, -1.43)
    [vertices:8]{area:1.95833}  (-2.5, -1.5),   (-2.5, -0.5),   (-2.5, -0.5),   (-4.45833, -0.5),   (-4.45833, -0.5),   (-4.45833, -1.5),   (-4.45833, -1.5),   (-2.5, -1.5),
Cell #8 contains a point: (-3.33, -0.95)
    [vertices:8]{area:3.41267}  (-2.5, -0.5),   (-2.5, 1.45833),    (-2.5, 1.45833),    (-4.24264, 1.24264),    (-4.24264, 1.24264),    (-4.45833, -0.5),   (-4.45833, -0.5),   (-2.5, -0.5),
Cell #9 contains a point: (-2.38, -2.86)
    [vertices:10]{area:1.25}    (-1.5, -2.5),   (-1.5, -1.5),   (-1.5, -1.5),   (-2.5, -1.5),   (-2.5, -1.5),   (-2.5, -2.5),   (-2.5, -2.5),   (-2, -3),   (-2, -3),   (-1.5, -2.5),
Cell #10 contains a point: (-2.38, -1.90)
    [vertices:8]{area:1}    (-1.5, -1.5),   (-1.5, -0.5),   (-1.5, -0.5),   (-2.5, -0.5),   (-2.5, -0.5),   (-2.5, -1.5),   (-2.5, -1.5),   (-1.5, -1.5),
Cell #11 contains a point: (-2.38, -0.95)
    [vertices:8]{area:1.95833}  (-1.5, 1.45833),    (-2.5, 1.45833),    (-2.5, 1.45833),    (-2.5, -0.5),   (-2.5, -0.5),   (-1.5, -0.5),   (-1.5, -0.5),   (-1.5, 1.45833),
Cell #12 contains a point: (-1.43, -3.33)
    [vertices:12]{area:1.875}   (-0.5, -3.5),   (-0.5, -2.5),   (-0.5, -2.5),   (-1.5, -2.5),   (-1.5, -2.5),   (-2, -3),   (-2, -3),   (-2, -3.75),    (-2, -3.75),    (-1, -4),   (-1, -4),   (-0.5, -3.5),
Cell #13 contains a point: (-1.43, -2.38)
    [vertices:8]{area:1}    (-0.5, -2.5),   (-0.5, -1.5),   (-0.5, -1.5),   (-1.5, -1.5),   (-1.5, -1.5),   (-1.5, -2.5),   (-1.5, -2.5),   (-0.5, -2.5),
Cell #14 contains a point: (-1.90, -1.90)
    [vertices:8]{area:1}    (-0.5, -1.5),   (-0.5, -0.5),   (-0.5, -0.5),   (-1.5, -0.5),   (-1.5, -0.5),   (-1.5, -1.5),   (-1.5, -1.5),   (-0.5, -1.5),
Cell #15 contains a point: (-1.90, -0.95)
    [vertices:8]{area:1.95833}  (-0.5, 1.45833),    (-1.5, 1.45833),    (-1.5, 1.45833),    (-1.5, -0.5),   (-1.5, -0.5),   (-0.5, -0.5),   (-0.5, -0.5),   (-0.5, 1.45833),
Cell #16 contains a point: (0.48, -5.24)
Cell #17 contains a point: (-0.48, -4.29)
    [vertices:8]{area:0.75} (1, -4),    (0.5, -3.5),    (0.5, -3.5),    (-0.5, -3.5),   (-0.5, -3.5),   (-1, -4),   (-1, -4),   (1, -4),
Cell #18 contains a point: (0.95, -3.81)
    [vertices:8]{area:1}    (0.5, -3.5),    (0.5, -2.5),    (0.5, -2.5),    (-0.5, -2.5),   (-0.5, -2.5),   (-0.5, -3.5),   (-0.5, -3.5),   (0.5, -3.5),
Cell #19 contains a point: (0.95, -2.38)
    [vertices:8]{area:1}    (0.5, -2.5),    (0.5, -1.5),    (0.5, -1.5),    (-0.5, -1.5),   (-0.5, -1.5),   (-0.5, -2.5),   (-0.5, -2.5),   (0.5, -2.5),
Cell #20 contains a point: (-0.95, -1.43)
    [vertices:8]{area:1}    (0.5, -1.5),    (0.5, -0.5),    (0.5, -0.5),    (-0.5, -0.5),   (-0.5, -0.5),   (-0.5, -1.5),   (-0.5, -1.5),   (0.5, -1.5),
Cell #21 contains a point: (-0.48, -0.95)
    [vertices:10]{area:2.71875} (1, -0),    (1, 1.33333),   (1, 1.33333),   (-0.5, 1.45833),    (-0.5, 1.45833),    (-0.5, -0.5),   (-0.5, -0.5),   (0.5, -0.5),    (0.5, -0.5),    (1, -0),
Cell #22 contains a point: (1.90, -3.33)
    [vertices:12]{area:1.82843} (1.82843, -3.82843),    (2, -3),    (2, -3),    (1.5, -2.5),    (1.5, -2.5),    (0.5, -2.5),    (0.5, -2.5),    (0.5, -3.5),    (0.5, -3.5),    (1, -4),    (1, -4),    (1.82843, -3.82843),
Cell #23 contains a point: (1.43, -2.86)
    [vertices:10]   (1.5, -0.585786),   (1.9375, -1.5), (1.9375, -1.5), (0.5, -1.5),    (0.5, -1.5),    (0.5, -2.5),    (0.5, -2.5),    (1.5, -2.5),    (1.5, -2.5),    (1.5, -0.585786),
Cell #24 contains a point: (1.90, -1.43)
    [vertices:12]   (1.9375, -1.5), (1.5, -2.41421),    (1.5, -2.41421),    (1.5, -0.5),    (1.5, -0.5),    (1, -0),    (1, -0),    (0.5, -0.5),    (0.5, -0.5),    (0.5, -1.5),    (0.5, -1.5),    (1.9375, -1.5),
Cell #25 contains a point: (2.38, -2.86)
    [vertices:6]{area:0.478553} (2, -3),    (1.5, -0.585786),   (1.5, -0.585786),   (1.5, -2.5),    (1.5, -2.5),    (2, -3),
Cell #26 contains a point: (2.38, -1.90)
    [vertices:6]{area:0.837468} (1.5, -2.41421),    (2.375, -0.5),  (2.375, -0.5),  (1.5, -0.5),    (1.5, -0.5),    (1.5, -2.41421),
Cell #27 contains a point: (2.38, -0.95)
    [vertices:10]{area:1.62731} (2.375, -0.5),  (1.44949, 1.44949), (1.44949, 1.44949), (1, 1.33333),   (1, 1.33333),   (1, -0),    (1, -0),    (1.5, -0.5),    (1.5, -0.5),    (2.375, -0.5),
Cell #28 contains segment start point: (3.50, -5.50)
Cell #29 contains a segment: (3.50, -5.50) -> (3.50, 3.00)
Cell #30 contains segment start point: (3.50, 3.00)

corresponding Python code used to generate this visualization:
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.spatial import Voronoi, voronoi_plot_2d

# Definicja punktów
positions = np.array([
    [0.476191, -0.952381], [-0, -0.952381],
    [-0.476191, -0.952381], [-0.476191, -1.42857],
    [-0.952381, -1.42857], [-1.90476, -0.952381],
    [-1.42857, -1.42857], [-1.90476, -1.42857],
    [-2.38095, -1.90476], [-1.42857, -2.38095],
    [-1.42857, -1.90476], [-0.952381, -2.85714],
    [-0.952381, -3.33333], [-0, -3.80952],
    [0.952381, -4.28571], [0.476191, -4.28571],
    [0.476191, -3.80952], [0.952381, -3.33333],
    [0.476191, -3.33333], [-0, -2.38095],
    [0.476191, -2.38095], [0.952381, -1.90476],
    [0.476191, -1.90476], [-0, -1.90476],
    [0.476191, -0.476191], [-0.952381, -0.952381],
    [0.476191, -1.42857], [-0.476191, -2.38095],
    [-0.952381, -2.38095], [-2.38095, -2.85714],
    [-1.90476, -3.33333], [-1.42857, -3.33333],
    [-0, -2.85714], [-0.476191, -2.85714],
    [-0, -3.33333], [-0, -4.76191],
    [0.952381, -2.38095], [0.952381, -2.85714],
    [0.476191, -2.85714], [-0.476191, -1.90476],
    [0.952381, -3.80952], [1.42857, -2.85714],
    [1.90476, -2.38095], [0.952381, -4.76191],
    [-0.476191, -5.2381], [0.476191, -5.2381],
    [1.90476, -3.33333], [-2.85714, -2.38095],
    [-2.38095, -1.42857], [-2.38095, -0.952381],
    [-1.42857, -2.85714], [-1.90476, -1.90476],
    [1.42857, -1.90476], [2.38095, -2.85714],
    [2.38095, -1.42857], [2.38095, -0.952381],
    [1.90476, -1.42857], [2.38095, -1.90476],
    [-1.90476, -2.38095], [0.952381, -0.952381],
    [-3.33333, -3.33333], [-3.80952, -2.38095],
    [-3.80952, -1.42857], [-3.33333, -1.90476],
    [-3.33333, -0.952381], [-0.476191, -4.28571],
    [-0, -1.42857], [-0.952381, -1.90476]
])

# Definicja segmentów
segments = np.array([
    [[-6.5, -5.5], [3.5, -5.5]],
    [[3.5, -5.5], [3.5, 3]],
    [[3.5, 3], [-6.5, 3]],
    [[-6.5, 3], [-6.5, -5.5]]
])

# Generowanie diagramu Voronoi
vor = Voronoi(positions)

# Rysowanie diagramu Voronoi
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
voronoi_plot_2d(vor, ax=ax, show_vertices=False, line_colors='blue', line_width=1.5, point_size=5)

# Dodanie punktów źródłowych
ax.plot(positions[:, 0], positions[:, 1], 'ro', label="Source Points (head positions)")

# Dodanie segmentów
for segment in segments:
    ax.plot(segment[:, 0], segment[:, 1], 'k-', lw=2, label="Segments (room end)")

# Ustawienia wykresu
ax.set_title("Voronoi Diagram Example")
ax.legend()
ax.set_aspect('equal')

# Wyświetlenie wykresu
plt.show()


EDIT: Thanks for suggestion from: @MSalters I was able to construct Voronoi diagram, which looks almost OK:

I multiplied all points (also segment's points) with 100 (meters to centimeters) then when drawing I divided points with 100. Now it looks almost OK, but some lines are going through points and other cells.

"Coordinates of the input points and endpoints of the input segments should have integral type...restriction is permanent" - the documentation clearly states that your use case is not at all supported. As the documentation notes, 32 bits is a lot. Your head position in a room can be expressed in nanometers. At that scale, hair growing becomes an issue.

According to Boost Voronoi Advanced Tutorial it is possible to change: " In case the user is not satisfied with the precision that the 32-bit integer grid provides or would like to retrieve coordinates of the output geometries within a smaller relative error, follow the next paragraph." and in next paragraph they are changing into int64_t input type, so there should be possibility of changing into floating point type.

Quoting from the documentation of the type traits struct used in that tutorial: Voronoi coordinate type traits make it possible to extend algorithm
input coordinate range to any user provided integer type. If you want floating point inputs and cannot expand the range to a large chunk of integers, this is not the library for you.

int64 not good enough? Nanometers too big? You know the position of people's heads down to attometer precision?! How did you defeat the Heisenberg uncertainty principle?

Even int32 is enough if I just convert from meters to centimeters. I just wanted to stay in meters, but I've changed my mind:D.

Looks to me the "spurious" lines are due to you trying plot polygons as if they're a single linestring. That doesn't work because you accidentally draw lines between two vertices from adjacent cells.
You could painstakingly retrace your path to a common vertex and continue from there. I'd say it's better to plot them as individual series:
QLineSeries* voronoiEdgesSeries = new QLineSeries();
voronoiEdgesSeries->setName("Voronoi Edges");
for (QPointF const& p : cellPolygon) {
    voronoiEdgesSeries->append(p.x() / SCALE, p.y() / SCALE);
    std::cout << "\t(" << p.x() / SCALE << ", " << p.y() / SCALE << "),";
}
chart->addSeries(voronoiEdgesSeries);
chart->legend()->markers(voronoiEdgesSeries)[0]->setVisible(false);

Note also, that since boost::geometry::is_valid is true, then by definition your polygon is already closed: no need to repeat the first point.
Here's a demo, scaling the inputs by 2^10:
Live Compiler Explorer?
#include <format>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

#include <QtCharts/QBarLegendMarker>
#include <QtCharts/QChartView>
#include <QtCharts/QLineSeries>
#include <QtCharts/QScatterSeries>
#include <QtWidgets/QApplication>
#include <QtWidgets/QMainWindow>

#include <boost/geometry.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/box.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/point.hpp>
#include <boost/polygon/point_data.hpp>
#include <boost/polygon/polygon.hpp>
#include <boost/polygon/voronoi.hpp>
#include <boost/polygon/voronoi_diagram.hpp>
#include <boost/polygon/gmp_override.hpp>

using namespace QtCharts;

struct Position {
    using coordinate_type = double;

    coordinate_type x, y;
};

using coordinate_type = Position::coordinate_type;
using segment_type    = boost::polygon::segment_data<coordinate_type>;
using VoronoiDiagram  = boost::polygon::voronoi_diagram<coordinate_type>;

/// settings necessarily for boost to be able to use Position as points:
template <> struct boost::polygon::geometry_concept<Position> {
    typedef point_concept type;
};

template <> struct boost::polygon::point_traits<Position> {
    using coordinate_type = ::coordinate_type;

    static inline coordinate_type get(Position const& point, boost::polygon::orientation_2d orient) {
        return (orient == boost::polygon::HORIZONTAL) ? point.x : point.y;
    }
};
using polygonF = boost::geometry::model::polygon<Position, /*ClockWise=*/false, /*Closed=*/false>;

/// settings required to use boost::geometry::area(polygonF):
namespace boost { namespace geometry { namespace traits {
    template <> struct tag<Position> { using type = point_tag; };
    template <> struct coordinate_type<Position> { using type = Position::coordinate_type; };
    template <> struct coordinate_system<Position> { using type = cs::cartesian; };
    template <> struct dimension<Position> : boost::mpl::int_<2> {};
    template <> struct access<Position, 0> {
        static ::coordinate_type get(Position const& p) { return p.x; }
        static void              set(Position& p, ::coordinate_type const& value) { p.x = value; }
    };
    template <> struct access<Position, 1> {
        static ::coordinate_type get(Position const& p) { return p.y; }
        static void              set(Position& p, ::coordinate_type const& value) { p.y = value; }
    };
}}} // namespace boost::geometry::traits

QPolygonF verticesOfCell(VoronoiDiagram::cell_type const& voronoiCell) {
    QPolygonF polygon;

    auto const* edge = voronoiCell.incident_edge();
    do {
        if (!edge)
            break;

        if (edge->is_primary()) {
            if (edge->is_finite()) {
                auto v0 = edge->vertex0();
                auto v1 = edge->vertex1();
                polygon << QPointF{v0->x(), v0->y()};
                polygon << QPointF{v1->x(), v1->y()};
            }
        }
        edge = edge->next();
    } while (edge != voronoiCell.incident_edge());

    return polygon;
}
polygonF toBoostPolygon(QPolygonF const& polygonQt) {
    polygonF polygon;
    for (auto const& p : polygonQt)
        polygon.outer().emplace_back(p.x(), p.y());
    return polygon;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    //////////////// configuration points and segments:
    std::vector<Position> positions = {
        {0.476191, -0.952381}, {-0, -0.952381},        {-0.476191, -0.952381}, {-0.476191, -1.42857},
        {-0.952381, -1.42857}, {-1.90476, -0.952381},  {-1.42857, -1.42857},   {-1.90476, -1.42857},
        {-2.38095, -1.90476},  {-1.42857, -2.38095},   {-1.42857, -1.90476},   {-0.952381, -2.85714},
        {-0.952381, -3.33333}, {-0, -3.80952},         {0.952381, -4.28571},   {0.476191, -4.28571},
        {0.476191, -3.80952},  {0.952381, -3.33333},   {0.476191, -3.33333},   {-0, -2.38095},
        {0.476191, -2.38095},  {0.952381, -1.90476},   {0.476191, -1.90476},   {-0, -1.90476},
        {0.476191, -0.476191}, {-0.952381, -0.952381}, {0.476191, -1.42857},   {-0.476191, -2.38095},
        {-0.952381, -2.38095}, {-2.38095, -2.85714},   {-1.90476, -3.33333},   {-1.42857, -3.33333},
        {-0, -2.85714},        {-0.476191, -2.85714},  {-0, -3.33333},         {-0, -4.76191},
        {0.952381, -2.38095},  {0.952381, -2.85714},   {0.476191, -2.85714},   {-0.476191, -1.90476},
        {0.952381, -3.80952},  {1.42857, -2.85714},    {1.90476, -2.38095},    {0.952381, -4.76191},
        {-0.476191, -5.2381},  {0.476191, -5.2381},    {1.90476, -3.33333},    {-2.85714, -2.38095},
        {-2.38095, -1.42857},  {-2.38095, -0.952381},  {-1.42857, -2.85714},   {-1.90476, -1.90476},
        {1.42857, -1.90476},   {2.38095, -2.85714},    {2.38095, -1.42857},    {2.38095, -0.952381},
        {1.90476, -1.42857},   {2.38095, -1.90476},    {-1.90476, -2.38095},   {0.952381, -0.952381},
        {-3.33333, -3.33333},  {-3.80952, -2.38095},   {-3.80952, -1.42857},   {-3.33333, -1.90476},
        {-3.33333, -0.952381}, {-0.476191, -4.28571},  {-0, -1.42857},         {-0.952381, -1.90476}};

    auto SCALE = std::pow(2.0, 10);

    std::vector<segment_type> segments;
    segments.emplace_back(Position{-6.5, -5.5},
                          Position{3.5, -5.5}); // for clang can be compile error, for g++ compiles
    segments.emplace_back(Position{3.5, -5.5}, Position{3.5, 3});
    segments.emplace_back(Position{3.5, 3}, Position{-6.5, 3});
    segments.emplace_back(Position{-6.5, 3}, Position{-6.5, -5.5});

    for (Position& p : positions) {
        p.x *= SCALE;
        p.y *= SCALE;
    }
    for (auto& s : segments) {
        s.low({s.low().x() * SCALE, s.low().y() * SCALE});
        s.high({s.high().x() * SCALE, s.high().y() * SCALE});
    }

    //////////////// construction of Voronoi diagram + printing cells
    VoronoiDiagram vd;
    boost::polygon::construct_voronoi(    //
        begin(positions), end(positions), //
        begin(segments), end(segments),   //
        &vd);

    // SCALE = 1;

    //////////////// Qt's part - set up Widgets
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QMainWindow  window;
    QChart*      chart = new QChart();
    chart->setTitle("Voronoi Diagram Example");
    chart->setAnimationOptions(QChart::NoAnimation);

    {
        QScatterSeries* pointsSeries = new QScatterSeries();
        pointsSeries->setName("Source Points (head positions)");
        pointsSeries->setMarkerSize(10.0);

        for (auto const& pos : positions)
            pointsSeries->append(pos.x / SCALE, pos.y / SCALE);

        chart->addSeries(pointsSeries);
    }

    QLineSeries* segmentsSeries = new QLineSeries();
    segmentsSeries->setName("Segments (room end)");

    for (unsigned int cell_index = 0; auto cell : vd.cells()) {
        if (cell.contains_point()) {
            switch (cell.source_category()) {
                case boost::polygon::SOURCE_CATEGORY_SINGLE_POINT: {
                    size_t index = cell.source_index();
                    auto   p     = positions.at(index);
                    std::cout << std::format("Cell #{} contains a point: ({:.2f}, {:.2f})", cell_index,
                                             p.x / SCALE, p.y / SCALE)
                              << std::endl;
                    break;
                }
                case boost::polygon::SOURCE_CATEGORY_SEGMENT_START_POINT: {
                    size_t index = cell.source_index() - positions.size();
                    auto   p0    = low(segments.at(index));
                    std::cout << std::format("Cell #{} contains segment start point: ({:.2f}, {:.2f})",
                                             cell_index, p0.x() / SCALE, p0.y() / SCALE)
                              << std::endl;
                    break;
                }
                case boost::polygon::SOURCE_CATEGORY_SEGMENT_END_POINT: {
                    size_t index = cell.source_index() - positions.size();
                    auto   p1    = high(segments.at(index));
                    std::cout << std::format("Cell #{} contains segment end point: ({:.2f}, {:.2f})",
                                             cell_index, p1.x() / SCALE, p1.y() / SCALE)
                              << std::endl;
                    break;
                }
                case boost::polygon::SOURCE_CATEGORY_INITIAL_SEGMENT:
                case boost::polygon::SOURCE_CATEGORY_REVERSE_SEGMENT:
                case boost::polygon::SOURCE_CATEGORY_GEOMETRY_SHIFT:
                case boost::polygon::SOURCE_CATEGORY_BITMASK: break;
            }

            auto cellPolygon = verticesOfCell(cell);
            if (!cellPolygon.empty()) {
                std::cout << "\t[vertices:" << cellPolygon.size() << "]";
                {
                    std::string reason;
                    if (auto boostPolygon = toBoostPolygon(cellPolygon);
                            boost::geometry::is_valid(boostPolygon, reason)) {
                        std::cout << "{area:" << boost::geometry::area(boostPolygon) / SCALE / SCALE << "}";
                    } else {
                        std::cerr << "{INVALID:" << reason << "}";
                        return 3;
                    }
                }
                {
                    QLineSeries* voronoiEdgesSeries = new QLineSeries();
                    voronoiEdgesSeries->setName("Voronoi Edges");
                    for (QPointF const& p : cellPolygon) {
                        voronoiEdgesSeries->append(p.x() / SCALE, p.y() / SCALE);
                        std::cout << "\t(" << p.x() / SCALE << ", " << p.y() / SCALE << "),";
                    }
                    chart->addSeries(voronoiEdgesSeries);
                    chart->legend()->markers(voronoiEdgesSeries)[0]->setVisible(false);
                }

                std::cout << std::endl;
            }
        } else {
            size_t index = cell.source_index() - positions.size();
            auto   p0    = low(segments.at(index));
            auto   p1    = high(segments.at(index));
            std::cout << std::format("Cell #{} contains a segment: ({:.2f}, {:.2f}) -> ({:.2f}, {:.2f})",
                                     cell_index, p0.x() / SCALE, p0.y() / SCALE, p1.x() / SCALE,
                                     p1.y() / SCALE)
                      << std::endl;
        }
        ++cell_index;
    }

    //////////////// Qt: setting up charts && drawing && showing:
    for (auto const& segment : segments) {
        auto p0 = segment.low();
        auto p1 = segment.high();
        segmentsSeries->append(p0.x() / SCALE, p0.y() / SCALE);
        segmentsSeries->append(p1.x() / SCALE, p1.y() / SCALE);
    }

    chart->addSeries(segmentsSeries);

    chart->createDefaultAxes();
    chart->setDropShadowEnabled(false);

    QChartView* chartView = new QChartView(chart);
    chartView->setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);

    window.setCentralWidget(chartView);
    window.resize(800, 600);
    window.show();

    return app.exec();
}

With a live demo:

The image:


It solved all problems I faced, thanks a lot for solution and improving my code!

BTW. I see that something wrong is with two lowest points and cells closest to them: those points look to be out of cells. It is because those edges are "curved", so instead of line we should connect them with some kind of arc which would contain the point.
